# javascript inheritance: Instance vs prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

When using inheritance, what is the difference and which approach would be better  between `ChildObject.prototype = new ParentObject();` or `ChildObject.prototype = ParentObject.prototype;`.

I have seen `ChildObject.prototype = new ParentObject();` in a Douglas Crockford example.

Comment: The 1st one adds ParentObject's in-constructor-defined own methods/properties to ChildObject's prototype, the 2nd one doesn't because it never executes the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Neither** of those.

Instead:

```
ChildObject.prototype = Object.create(ParentObject.prototype);
ChildObject.prototype.constructor = ChildObject;
```

combined with this line at the beginning of `ChildObject`:

```
ParentObject.call(this/*, appropriate args if any*/);
```

or if passing along *all* args:

```
ParentObject.apply(this, arguments); // `arguments` literally -- it's provided by the JavaScript engine
```

The problem with `ChildObject.prototype = new ParentObject();` is that it won't work if `ParentObject` expects arguments, as many (most?) constructors do. So the pattern doesn't work in a common (possibly majority) case.

The problem with `ChildObject.prototype = ParentObject.prototype;` is that then you have both of them pointing at the **same object**. So setting a property on `ChildObject.prototype` makes it show up on instances of `ParentObject` (since you've just set it on `ParentObject.prototype` as well).

The `Object.create` version defers calling `ParentObject` until you have an object to initialize, but gives you an object on which you can put the things specific to `ChildObject` instances. (The `constructor` backlink is to make the replacement object look like the default one `ChildObject` originally had; that didn't used to matter much, but it's actually used now by ES6 in some cases, and some libs used it before even if ES5 and earlier didn't [they just put it there].)

Finally: The single-argument version of `Object.create` can be shimmed for obsolete browsers from before 2009 when it was added in ES5, or you can use a factory function instead if you don't like partially-shimming things:

```
function objectCreate(proto) {
    function ctor() { }
    ctor.prototype = proto;
    return new ctor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

We usually use prototypes to supply methods - to avoid duplicating the same function for each instance of class. In other words, for something like...

```
ChildObject.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log('foo');
};
```

Now you probably see the problem with the second approach: modifying `ChildObject.prototype` will modify `ParentObject.prototype` as well (it's the same object after `ChildObject.prototype = ParentObject.prototype` line). That means all `ParentObject` in this example will have `foo` method available to them. Actually, it's not even correct to say that `ParentObject` is *parent* of `ChildObject` - both have the same prototype chain.

Yet there's another nasty side effect. Consider this:

```
function ParentObj() {}
function ChildObj() {}
ChildObj.prototype = ParentObj.prototype;
var i = new ParentObj();
console.log(i); // ParentObj {}
var j = new ChildObj();
console.log(j); // ParentObj {}
```

See, both prototypes, as they are the same object, have the same `constructor` property. So to distinguish between those, we'll have to introduce some flags in the constructor functions, essentially overriding the already existing mechanism.

Comment: If I understand correctly, doing `ChildObject.prototype = ParentObject.prototype` will cause that if one augments the prototype of ChildObject, it will augment the ParentObject's prototype as well?

Comment: Of course, as both _names_ resolve to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
ChildObject.prototype = ParentObject.prototype;
```

then your parent and child have the *same prototype*. With the latter,

```
ChildObject.prototype = new ParentObject();
```

the child's prototype is *the parent itself.*